# Arraylist empty when return

Tags: java, android, collections

I am working on an android project and I am facing a problem and the problem is:

> Arraylist empty when I return it.

Here is my java code:

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> container = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
            ArrayList<Object> itemRow = new ArrayList<Object>();
            JSONObject jsonObj =  new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray allElements = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Table");
            Log.i("allElements", "" + allElements);
            for (int i = 0; i < allElements.length(); i++) {
                itemRow.add(allElements.getJSONObject(i).getString("ParentName").toString());
                itemRow.add(allElements.getJSONObject(i).getString("ParentEmailID").toString());
                itemRow.add(allElements.getJSONObject(i).getString("ParentContact").toString());
                itemRow.add(allElements.getJSONObject(i).getString("ParentAddress").toString());
                itemRow.add(allElements.getJSONObject(i).getString("ParentProfilePictureName").toString());
                itemRow.add(allElements.getJSONObject(i).getString("StudentName").toString());
                Log.i("itemRow", "itemRow at index: " + i + ", " + itemRow);
                container.add(((i*2)/2), itemRow);
                itemRow.clear();
            }

            return container;
```

In this code I have two Arraylist one for contain all the elements and another one for storing single row of elements. These Arraylist are loaded from JSONArray, all is working fine and I can print data from item row (Arraylist which take single row) and store into main Arraylist (container).

But when I return this Arraylist (container) and print in logcat it shows empty Arraylist like

```
[[], [], [], [], []].
```

I cannot understand why this happen please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop clearing the list, and it won't be empty anymore:

```
itemRow.clear();
```

You should create a new list at each iteration. Put the following line of code inside the for loop:

```
ArrayList<Object> itemRow = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Remember that Java passes references to objects. So the container list holds a reference to the list you add to it. It doesn't make a copy of the list. So your current code adds several references to the same list object to the container list, and you clear the list each time you add it. It thus contains N references to the same empty list at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

Because you did, It still refers to the object that is added to `container`

```
itemRow.clear();
```

You might like to reinitialize it

```
itemRow = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assessment is misleading/incorrect, the ArrayList is **not** empty, and actually contains five elements.

Each *element* of the array list is an empty list.  This is because of the last two lines within your loop:

```
container.add(((i*2)/2), itemRow);
itemRow.clear();
```

The first line adds the itemRow to the container, as you expect.  The next line calls `clear()` on the row you've just added - so *everything in the container will always be empty* by the time your method exits.

It looks like this issue was caused by you trying to reuse the same `itemRow` object throughout the method, which isn't going to work.  To fix your problem, move the

```
ArrayList<Object> itemRow = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

constructor inside the loop (as the first line), and then stop calling `clear()` on it at the end.  Now each JSON element will have a separate row list created for it, and once you've added these to the `container` they will maintain their contents.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that container actually copies every arraylist in itself is not right. it refers to those already created rather having copies of each List.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
container.add(((i*2)/2), itemRow.clone());
```

as it about JAVA referencing...